# Missing or invalid "path" property in function "func_name" for http event in serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

When I'm trying to deploy to aws, I've got an error due to **Missing or invalid "path" property** .

```
serverless deploy -v
#OR
serverless run --watch
```

```
# serveless file

service:
  name: aws-nodejs-ecma-script

# Add the serverless-webpack plugin
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10

functions:
  events_get:
    handler: get.handler
    events:
      - http:
        method: get
        path: test
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well the problem was a bad indent.

```
# solution one
functions:
  events_get:
    handler: get.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: test

# solution two
functions:
  events_get:
    handler: get.handler
    events:
      - http: get test
```

source :

- https://forum.serverless.com/t/error-on-deploy-missing-or-invalid-path-property-in-function/2365
- https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/services#contents